# Making a normal "submit" button that will get me to the "div id="example"

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make a `submit` button that when I click it, it will get me to the for example `<div id="Home">` without Javascript? I already tried with different ways but as always the first page is showing all tags from other ID's page's. I already have the Javascript code but I don't want to use, I want to do all this by simple HTML tags, if possible please help.

Comment: use links for navigation, not buttons. then you just use `<a href=#id5>5</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

why not do something like

```
<a href="#Home">submit</a>
```

Comment: Not even that is working. I don't know what wrong I did... Even with `<a href=` it's still not working and it's showing down the other ID's tags...

Comment: Could you show me some of your code so I can maybe see what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Give your `div` an `id` such as

```
<div id="#home">
```

and then the link should link to the `#home`.

```
<a href="#home">
```

That should work

Try it here
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor

Comment: Not even that is working. I don't know what wrong I did... Even with `<a href=` it's still not working and it's showing down the other ID's tags...

Comment: Also, is there a reason you dont want to use the js you have?

Comment: I mean on the other tags below the button that should get me to that ID and I am begginer after all and want to do step by step, which means first only HTML and after that I'll go with CSS, JS etc...

Comment: Hang on. Is your "home" a page, or a div?? And is the button on a different page?

Comment: No, I made `<div id="Home">` `<p>Hello world!</p>` `</div>` - Button is on the beggining of the code, after 2 boxes, text and password, pressing that button should go to `<div id="Home">` and there are other tags...

Comment: are you missing the `#`. The link should be `<a href="#home">` and the div to have `id="#home"`

Comment: The #home will only scroll to that div. So it really only works if the button is far away. Because then the browser will scroll up or down to go to that div. If they are only inches away on a large screen like a desktop or laptop, then you would not see the results. You can test this by adding a lot of text, maybe 10 paragraphs or so, where you need to scroll down, and see if it scrolls up

Comment: Also, sorry to waste your time. the div does not need the # but the link does.

Try this that I made https://jsfiddle.net/4nz87ezk/

If that doesnt work, can you post your code there in the html, click save and give me the link. I will have a look

Comment: Thank you for your help but this doesn't work. Well, this case should be closed, I'll find the solution somewhere. Thank you again for your helping!

Comment: No problem. Its good to remember though the roles that each html, css and javascript play, as well as its limitations. Ordinarily html is for content, such as images, text, and css is for stying those contents. and javascript is for functionality. Html can do some functionality but not a great deal.